# How to remove a plugin from Gatsby at build time?

Tags: gatsby

My gatsby project is used to build many different sites.
I've been customizing the config of some plugins in gatsby-node.js for some time, using the [onPreInit](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/reference/config-files/gatsby-node/#onPreInit) hook.

Like this:

```js
exports.onPreInit = async ({ actions, store }) => {
  const { setPluginStatus } = actions
  const state = store.getState()
  const someConfig = getSomeConfig()

  const pluginToCustomize = state.flattenedPlugins.find(
    (plugin) => plugin.name === 'gatsby-plugin-to-customize'
  )
  setPluginStatus(
    {
      pluginOptions: {
        ...pluginToCustomize.pluginOptions,
        config: someConfig,
      },
    },
    pluginToCustomize
  )
}
```

And it works.

Now, I'd like to completely get rid of a certain plugin for a certain site.
Is there a way to do that?

I tried redefining `state.flattenedPlugins`

```js
state.flattenedPlugins = state.flattenedPlugins.filter(
  (plugin) => plugin.name !== 'plugin-I-do-not-want'
)
```

But no luck.

Looking at the content of `actions` and `store`, there seems to be no built-in function to remove a plugin completely.

The only hack that comes to mind right now is to have some kind of pre-build script that would comment out the plugin from gatsby-config.js. And I don't like that solution.

Comment: Why don't you use environment variables to conditionally add plugins inside `gatsby-config`?

Comment: Interesting idea, thanks! I'd rather have the conditional plugin come from the CMS, there might be a way to make that work.